# Integration of a function of interpolating functions

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

I need to calculate the integral of a function of interpolating functions. Being more specific, the function I want to integrate is the following

```
derUp[tau_] = 1/(drad[tau] + Sqrt[drad[tau]^2 + ftau[tau]])
```

where `drad[tau_] = D[rad[tau], tau]` and `ftau[tau_] = 1 - (2 mm[tau])/rad[tau]`. 
`rad[tau]` and `mm[tau]` are the numerical solutions of a system of differential equations, and therefore defined as interpolating functions.

The conceptual problem that I seem not being able to overcome/understand is that it seems to be impossible to calculate the following thing

```
func = Integrate[derUp[tau],{tau, 0, tau'}]
```

with `tau'` being a variable instead of a number. The reason behind this calculation is that I need to obtain `func` as a function of `tau`.

A solution I have tried to implement is `FunctionInterpolation`, that seems to works very well when the function to integrate depends on two variables, as specified in other posts that I have read on this forum, but that does not seem to be applicable to the one-variable case (at least I have not figured it out).

Comment: Try `func[taup_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[derUp[tau],{tau, 0, taup}]` and call `func[1.]`.

Comment: Doesn't `Integrate[derUp[tau],tau]` (without explicit limits) give you what you need?

Comment: @mikado, being m[tau] and rr[tau] interpolating functions, Mathematica seems to be unable to calculate the integral using ```Integrate[derUp[tau],tau]```.

Comment: @Vale.  It appears that indefinite integration can be applied to something with `Head` `InterpolatingFunction`.  Can you apply `FunctionInterpolation` to reduce your expressions to a single `InterpolatingFunction`?

Comment: You can convert your integral into an equivalent ODE problem and use `NDSolve[]` to construct the required solution.

Comment: Consider converting `1/(drad[tau] + Sqrt[drad[tau]^2 + ftau[tau]])` into a new `InterpolatingFunction`, using `FunctionInterpolation`.  Be sure to set the (poorly documented) `InterpolationPoints` option to a sufficiently large number.  Then, integrate the new `InterpolatingFunction`.  It is not, however, clear whether there is much advantage here in using `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate`, because the solution is numerical in either case.  Probably, `func` should be defined as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information in the question, but this approach fits one interpretation of the description of the situation.  One can do the integral in the original `NDSolve` calls that generated `rad` and `mm`.  (This may be what J.M. was suggesting in a comment.  Or he may have meant executing a separate `NDSolve` call.  I would recommend the approach given below.)

Example:  The first two lines of the ODE system are uninteresting.  The third line computes the integral of `r[t]`, `r'[t]`, and `m[t]`.

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{
   r''[t] + r'[t] - 1/3 r[t] == 0, r[0] == 1, r'[0] == -1,
   m''[t] + m'[t] - 1/4 m[t] == 0, m[0] == 1/4, m'[0] == -1,
   f'[t] == 1/(r'[t] + Sqrt[r'[t]^2 + (1 - (2 m[t])/r[t])]), f[0] == 0
   },
  {r, m, f}, {t, 0, 10}]

ListPlot[{r, m, f} /. sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The integral is returned as an `InterpolatingFunction`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you Michael, your approach is very elegant and effective. I didn't specify the system where m[tau] and rad[tau] came from to avoid having a very long post.

Comment: @Vale You're welcome. :)